# How to call a custom asyncloader from a fragment class

Tags: android, android-fragments, asynctaskloader

I am trying to use `AsyncTaskLoader` to load data from a server and then I will put it in a list view later on. I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3d9BeWqlfTk) on YouTube. However, when I try to call the loader from another class which extends fragment, the loader won't accept the context.

I tried:

1. `getActivity()`
2. `getActivity().getApllicationContext()`

Neither worked.

Comment: Some sample code showing your problem would be greatly beneficial.

Comment: Please post your code and the stacktrace with the error thrown.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be creating a `Loader` directly, you need to use the `LoaderManager` and call the `initLoader()` method. The manager is acquired using your `Activity`, so it already provides the correct context. If you are using the support library to support pre-3.0 devices, be sure to derive your `Activity` from `FragmentActivity`.